# help changing footer on home page

Tags: editing

I wonder if you can help. I need to make some changes to the text on the bottom part of our home-page but I'm not sure how to. This site was designed for us by another agency and although I have access to the template and the back of it I can't seem to figure out how to edit the text on the footer of the site. help please!
Thanks,
Carolina

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're not a web developer? This is a very broad question unfortunately which will make helping hard. It depends almost entirely on how the previous agency decided to build your website, as "a footer" is not built-in functionality, but instead part of the design.

Typically, a footer would be controlled from a `_layout.twig` file in the templates directory. The content inside it may be "hard coded" or dynamically controlled from the CMS - there's no way for me to know. You'd need to look at the content of that file and see if you can find any text matching the text you see in your footer. Be aware though, that a footer template is usually *site wide* and not specific to individual pages; a change in `_layout.twig` would most often mean a change everywhere on your website.

You may be best off getting in touch with the prior agency, or perhaps a freelancer, and asking them to take a look.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply. Much appreciated.

Comment: It's also possible there's are some variables you can control in the 'globals' section. If you have permissions to view, it they would be here: https://yoursite.com/cp/admin/globals/ (replace 'yoursite.com/cp' with the path to your Craft control panel).